# Create a factory class in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring

In my Java development, I often have to create factory classes for instantiating things: either because the actual class to be instantiated is only known at runtime, or to keep things tidy and testable/mockable.

Is there a quick way to generate the `create()` method from the class' constructor in IDEA? I found an easy way to generate a static `create`, but could not find a way to create a factory class w/o manual cut/paste.

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> might be helpful to you.  Toward the bottom there is an option to 'Replace Constructor with Factory Method.'

Comment: That's the one I was referring to when I said "an easy way to generate a static create". Useful, but not really direct.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) but its nothing related to IDE. Its nice and can create factory in predictable style always. Also it keeps source clean.